# How to setup array as parameters in request via Retrofit?

Tags: android, retrofit

I need to execute request via `Retrofit` :

```
url = http://ENDPOINT_URL/users/77?expand=followers,image,followees
```

Code :

```
@GET(ENDPOINT_URL+"users/{user_id}?expand=" WHAT NEED PRESENT HERE???)
void getUserInfo(@Path("user_id) int userId, String... expand)
```

For **userId** i use `Path` annotation, but how i can say to `Retrofit`, that I need to use array items separated via comma?

Comment: Remove expand from `@GET` and try this: `@Query("expand") String[] values` or using `List<String> values`. I think this should work

Comment: Or, use a `@QueryMap` and pass the formatted value (i.e. `followers,image,etc`) in the `expand` key. But you need to format the string before.